# Android Height of the Listview does not match the parent LinearLayout

Tags: android, listview, xamarin

I have the following code in my axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
p1:layout_width="fill_parent"
p1:layout_height="fill_parent"
p1:background="@android:color/white">
<ScrollView
    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
    p1:layout_height="match_parent"
    p1:layout_weight="1"
    p1:paddingLeft="16dp"
    p1:paddingRight="16dp"
    p1:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    p1:background="#ffffffff"
    p1:id="@+id/scrollView1">
    <LinearLayout
        p1:orientation="vertical"
        p1:minWidth="25px"
        p1:minHeight="25px"
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_height="match_parent"
        p1:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
        <TableLayout
            p1:minWidth="25px"
            p1:minHeight="25px"
            p1:layout_width="match_parent"
            p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            p1:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
            p1:stretchColumns="*">
            <TableRow
                ...
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
        <ListView
            p1:minWidth="25px"
            p1:id="@+id/lvPositions"
            p1:layout_width="match_parent"
            p1:layout_height="0dp"
            p1:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But although I have set the **height** of my listview to 0 and the **weight** to 1, my `Listview` does not expand to fill the whole `linearLayout`. When running the project on my device it has just a size of about 200px or less and more then 300px are left empty in the `linearlayout`.
How can I fix that?

Comment: why don't you use layout_height to match_parent ? in some cases you should define weight for all child views of a parent view.

Comment: @MohamamdFatemi I have done that before, but has not worked either

Comment: Did you try changing the height of your listView to wrap_content?

Comment: @YawAsare I tried it, but didn't work

Comment: @MoProg change the scrollview's layout_height to wrap_content and check it works ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe because you use the ListView inside a ScrollView, it may cause trouble, you can try to get rid of the ScrollView.

Comment: Yep, you are right. After removing the scrollview and the RelativeLayout, and some small changes, it finally worked. Thanks